# uicontrol Slider in Octave: minimum is at top, maximum at bottom

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider, octave, uicontrol

In my Matlab script, which I'm using with Octave, I have a `uicontrol` element in my figure, of `Style` `Slider`, which is essentially a regular scroll bar slider.

```
controls.slider.audio_1 = uicontrol( 'Style', 'Slider', ...
                                     'Position', [ 100 150 10 300 ], ...
                                     'Max', 100, 'Min', 1, ...
                                     'SliderStep', [ 0.01 0.01 ], ...
                                     'Units', 'normalized', ...
                                     'Value', 1 )
```

The orientation of the slider is determined by its geometry: it's 10px wide and 300px tall, making it into a vertical slider. I have not yet found a way to force the orientation.

But here comes the main point of my question: When I define the slider like this, the minimum value (defined by `Min`) is at the top! The slider works with it's minimum position at the top, and then the user has to pull it downwards to increase the value. I'd like to switch that around, such that the minimum is at the bottom, and the slider increases its value, when dragged upwards.

How do I do that?

Comment: Unintuitive, I agree. But does it matter? The value is simply the position. You can translate that however you want. `value = 100-position`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the issue is also one of compatability: I've noticed that it seems to depend on the Matlab and/or Octave version where the slider starts, or how it is orientated, having a way to force the orientation, etc. would make this a lot more portable.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have never noticed the slider being upside down in MATLAB (I've been using it since 5.3). Is this maybe a bug in specific versions of Octave?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm not even sure this is a bug: It might just be it's standard on the graphics package Matlab / Octave uses in the background. I.e. on some GUI packages, sliders start at the top.

Comment: Sure, it could be a GUI package thing in Octave. But I would consider an inconsistency like this as a bug. If i were to make an interface to a different UI toolkit for Octave, I'd put in effort to keep UI control behavior consistent. MATLAB has had 3 different UI implementations since I've been using it, they have always been very good at keeping it consistent, and I'd be surprised if you see this reversed scrollbar there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTSL! In [libgui/graphics/SliderControl.cc#l65](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/5aa9c885ea18/libgui/graphics/SliderControl.cc#l65) you'll find

```
bool vertical_slider = ( bb(2) < bb(3) );
slider->setOrientation (vertical_slider ? Qt::Vertical : Qt::Horizontal);
if (vertical_slider)
  slider->setInvertedAppearance (true);  // Matlab compatibility
```

Which is exactly what you are looking for. Then fire up `hg blame` to see who added the line when and have a look at the commit message:

```
$ hg log -r 23412
changeset:   23412:7b95435e96a4
user:        Rik <rik@octave.org>
date:        Tue Apr 18 16:35:38 2017 -0700
summary:     Reverse orientation of vertical uicontrol "sliders" for Matlab compatibility (bug #50818).
```

Aha!. So this was changed for compatibility on the development tree (aka default) in 2017. So the 4.2.x release doesn't see this yet but the next 4.4 release will have the change.

But you haven't mentioned your used GNU Octave version yet.

Comment: So, I'm looking at a bug right now? Btw. my Octave version is 4.2.1

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't call it a bug. What you see in 4.2.1 is how Qt (the used toolkit behaves) behaves per default and Rik decided to change Qt's default to match MATLABS behaviour. This is not always the case when MATLAB really behaves stupid, see the "WTF? MATLAB" category on the bugtracker

Comment: so, what should I do now? Wait for the new version and for now just accept the inverted sliders? Since the application is supposed to run with both Matlab *and* Octave, etc.

Comment: in your case I would just check if you [are running Octave](http://wiki.octave.org/Compatibility) and then invert it in software as Cris Luengo already suggested. Or you can grab the source tarball, patch Slider and compiled it yourself.

Comment: I decided I'll do exactly as you suggested. I'll provide an update once the new version of Octave gets released. I'll accept your answer, because I'll do as you suggest, you may wanna amend your solution with the idea of checking for octave and then acting accordingly.